# How do I select 8 random songs from top 50, with unique user_id?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am trying to get top 50 downloads, and then shuffling (randomizing) 8 results. Plus, the 8 results have to be unique user_id's. I came up with this so far:

```
Song.select('DISTINCT songs.user_id, songs.*').where(:is_downloadable => true).order('songs.downloads_count DESC').limit(50).sort_by{rand}.slice(0,8)
```

My only gripe with this is, the last part `.sort_by{rand}.slice(0,8)` is being done via Ruby. Any way I can do all this via Active Record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how the column `user_id` ended up in the table `songs`? That means you have one row for every combination of song and user? In a normalized schema, that would be an *n:m relationship* implemented with three tables:

```
song(song_id, ...)
usr(usr_id, ...)    -- "user" is a reserved word
download (song_id, user_id, ...) -- implementing the n:m relationship
```

The query in your question yields incorrect results. The same `user_id` can pop up multiple times. `DISTINCT` does not do what you seem to expect it to. You need [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) or some other method like [aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) or [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html).

You also need to use subqueries or [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), because this cannot be done in one step. When you use `DISTINCT` you cannot at the same time `ORDER BY random()`, because the sort order cannot disagree with the order dictated by `DISTINCT`. This query is certainly not trivial.

#### Simple case, top 50 songs

If you are happy to just pick the top 50 songs (not knowing how many duplicate user_ids are among them), this "simple" case will do:

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   songs
    WHERE  is_downloadable
    ORDER  BY downloads_count DESC
    LIMIT  50
    )
    , y AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
    FROM   x
    ORDER  BY user_id, downloads_count DESC -- pick most popular song per user
--  ORDER  BY user_id, random() -- pick random song per user
    )
SELECT *
FROM   y
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  8;
```

1. Get the 50 songs with the highest `download_count`. Users can show up multiple times.
2. Pick 1 song per user. Randomly or the most popular one, that's not defined in your question.
3. Pick 8 songs with now distinct `user_id` randomly.

You only need an **index** on `songs.downloads_count` for this to be fast:

```sql
CREATE INDEX songs_downloads_count_idx ON songs (downloads_count DESC);
```

#### Top 50 songs with unique user_id

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
    FROM   songs
    WHERE  is_downloadable
    ORDER  BY user_id, downloads_count DESC
    )
    , y AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   x
    ORDER  BY downloads_count DESC
    LIMIT  50
    )
SELECT *
FROM   y
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  8;
```

1. Get the song with the highest `download_count` per user. Every user can only show up once, so it has to be the one song with the highest `download_count`.
2. Pick the 50 with highest `downloads_count` from that.
3. Pick 8 songs from that randomly.

With a big table, performance will **suck**, because you have to find the best row for *every* user before you can proceed. A multi-column index will help, but it will still not be very fast:

```sql
CREATE INDEX songs_u_dc_idx ON songs (user_id, downloads_count DESC);
```

---

#### The same, faster

**If** duplicate `user_id`s among the top songs are **predictably rare**, you can use a **trick**. Pick just enough of the top downloads, so that the top 50 with unique `user_id` are certainly among them. After this step, proceed like above. This will be **much faster** with big tables, because the top n rows can be read from the top of an index quickly:

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   songs
    WHERE  is_downloadable
    ORDER  BY downloads_count DESC
    LIMIT  100 -- adjust to your secure estimate
    )
    , y AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
    FROM   x
    ORDER  BY user_id, downloads_count DESC
    )
    , z AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   y
    ORDER  BY downloads_count DESC
    LIMIT  50
    )
SELECT *
FROM   z
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  8;
```

The index from the simple case above will suffice to make it almost as fast as the simple case.

This would fall short if less than 50 distinct users are among the top 100 "songs".

All queries should work with PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.

---

If it has to be faster, yet, create a **materialized view** that holds the pre-selected top 50, and rewrite that table in regular intervals or triggered by events. If you make heavy use of this *and* the table is big, I would go for that. Otherwise it's not worth the overhead.

#### Generalized, improved solution

I later formalized and improved this approach further to be applicable to a whole class of similar problems under this [related question at dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am wondering if this can be done with AR. `user_id` is in songs, because every user has one or many songs

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: I am an expert with PostgreSQL, not so much with AR. You can execute the queries directly with `find_by_sql` -  as @Deefour advised. Generally ORMs **suck** with complex queries. They are primitive crutches that promise database agnostic implementation - for the price of suboptimal queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PostgreSQL's `RANDOM()` function in the order by, making it

```
___.order('songs.downloads_count DESC, RANDOM()').limit(8)
```

though this doesn't work though because PostgreSQL requires the columns used in the `ORDER BY` be found in the `SELECT`. You'll get an error like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

The only way to do what your'e asking all in SQL *(using PostgreSQL)* is with a subquery, which may or may not be a better solution for you. If it is, your best bet is to write out the full query/subquery using **[find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)**.

I'm happy to help come up with the SQL, though now that you know about `RANDOM()`, it should be pretty trivial.